# Need help to improve Hazelcast query performance

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I have around 200k records to store. I have implemented Java client to search records form hazelcast Map. I am not getting search result in expected time.

Once I make Hazelcast Like or In query it takes min 400 to 500 ms.

Can server and client side configuration be changed to improve this throughput?

I have stored the Java Bean information inside Map with key-value. I have also created index on one field. Implemented identity serialize mechanism also.

Server side configuration (Used XML file to setup server):

```
<map name="app-data">
    <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
    <statistics-enabled>false</statistics-enabled>
    <optimize-queries>false</optimize-queries>
    <cache-deserialized-values>INDEX-ONLY</cache-deserialized-values>
    <backup-count>0</backup-count>
    <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">2147483647</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <min-eviction-check-millis>100</min-eviction-check-millis>
    <merge-policy batch-size="100">com.hazelcast.map.merge.LatestUpdateMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    <read-backup-data>false</read-backup-data>
    <hot-restart enabled="false">
        <fsync>false</fsync>
    </hot-restart>
    <map-store enabled="false" initial-mode="LAZY">
        <write-delay-seconds>0</write-delay-seconds>
        <write-batch-size>1</write-batch-size>
    </map-store>
    <indexes>
        <index ordered="true">index</index>
    </indexes>
</map>

<data-serializable-factories>
        <data-serializable-factory factory-id="1">com.tmobile.services.cacheserver.config.hazelcast.cache.serialization.CacheServerDataSerializableFactory</data-serializable-factory>
```

Client code:

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();

    config.getSerializationConfig()
          .addDataSerializableFactory(
            CacheServerDataSerializableFactory.FACTORY_ID,
            new CacheServerDataSerializableFactory());

    config.getNetworkConfig().setAddresses(addresses).setConnectionAttemptPeriod(3000)
          .getSocketOptions().setBufferSize(256 * SocketOptions.KILO_BYTE);

    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(config);
    return hazelcastInstance;
```

I have used hazelcast version as 3.11.

Below is the object that I have used to store information.

```
    public class AppData implements IdentifiedDataSerializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonIgnore
    private Long index = 0l;

    private Integer appId = 0;

    public void setIndex(Integer index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public Integer getIndex() {
        return this.index;
    }

    public void setAppId(Integer appId) {
        this.appId = appId;
    }

    public Integer getAppId() {
        return this.appId;
    }

    @Override
    public final int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(this.getAppId());
    }

    @Override
    public void writeData(ObjectDataOutput out) throws IOException {
        out.writeLong(index);
        out.writeInt(appId);
    }

    @Override
    public void readData(ObjectDataInput in) throws IOException {

        this.index = in.readLong();
        this.appId = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public int getFactoryId() {
        return CacheServerDataSerializableFactory.APP_DATE_FACTORY_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public int getId() {
        return CacheServerDataSerializableFactory.APP_DATE_ID;
    }
}
```

I have used below query/predicate to filter data.

```
Predicate pred = new InPredicate(attribute, (Comparable[]) ((List) filterValue).toArray(new String[0]));
Collection<Object> items =  map.values(predicate);
```

Comment: Have you tried `<in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>`, That will help some queries but make `put()/get()` operations slower.

Comment: Can you share the object you store inside Hazlecast map, queries you’re running & Hazelcast version you’re running?

Comment: I have updated my question by sharing object, query/predicate and hazelcast version.

Answer (score 0):

@Prashant, since `IN` predicate just hit index n times & get the result directly, the only place you can improve is index copying behavior: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.1/manual/html-single/index.html#copying-indexes

You can set below property on member config & see the results:

`<property name="hazelcast.index.copy.behavior">NEVER</property>`

Please read the documentation about the index copy behaviors.